# Does NSManagedObjectContext's performBlock method guarantee the order of operations?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, core-data

The question pretty much covers it all.  If I put in N blocks into the queue for the NSManagedObjectContext, will it perform them all in order, guaranteed, or is there a chance that some of them might get scrambled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no reason why NSManagedObjectContext wouldn't use GCD internally, and GCD queues are strictly FIFO.  Of course I have no proof to confirm this, but it makes perfect sense to me since the goal of `performBlock` is thread safety, and performing only one operation at once in a given context, and why would Apple bother writing a system from the ground up when a perfectly functional one (GCD) already exists.

Comment: Dependencies are for when you are using more than one queue.  Every piece of literature and video on the subject says that the queues themselves are FIFO.  However, concurrent queues may *finish* tasks in seemingly random order since they will execute in parallel but they will *start* in FIFO.  This type of queue is inappropriate for a managed object context, though, given its goal of only performing one operation at any given time.

Comment: Then I guess I really misunderstood what I was reading on the subject.  Time to re-read the references.  Though... maybe I was confused by the ability of a queue to run multiple concurrent operations, which would then make dependencies make sense if one operation depends on the previous ones...

Comment: I think if you create a MOC with `.PrivateQueueConcurrencyType` type - so a temporary MOC basically, it is then concurrent, and although they start in FIFO, they will not finish in the same order, but only for `performBlock` can it happen, and it happened me too. I enqueued a **save** block last, but some other block finished last, and it caused me trouble.